# How to get what IP Address Ranges used by Visual Studio Online Load Testing Agents?

Tags: azure, load-testing, visual-studio

I need to setup IP Whitelisting in an environment that I need to run some Visual Studio Online Load Tests on. I was able to find some documentation as to what IP Addresses Visual Studio Online supposedly uses, but it doesn't seem to be accurate.

According to the FAQ (http://www.visualstudio.com/get-starte/load-testing-faq-vs) the Visual Studio Online Load Testing runs in the Azure US East data center. And according to the Microsoft Azure Datacenter IP Ranges (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) document I was able to determine what IP Addresses to whitelist for the Azure US East data center.

Unfortunately, when we setup IP Whitelisting in out environment for these IP Addresses, the Visual Studio Online Load Tests would run with errors. We were able to temporarily remove the IP Whitelist restriction and the tests all run successfully, so it has been determined that it's definitely the IP Whitelisting and not the Load Test setup that is at fault.

Does anyone know a definite way to find out what IP Addresses the Visual Studio Online Load Testing Agents are using? Also, is it possible that Visual Studio Online runs in any other data center than US East?

Comment: They do keep on updating Azure IP ranges; the current list is from July 1st, for instance. Make sure the list is current. Apart from that, your best bet may be to ask VS/Azure support.

Answer (score 0):

They have a feature in preview where you can reserve IP addresses that you can then whitelist.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/03/10/load-testing-applications-behind-firewall-using-trusted-ip.aspx